Why a larger uniformity has a smaller base?
This might be silly and easy, but I'm confused why, on the same set, a larger uniformity has a smaller base. Specifically, let $X$ be a set, and $(Y, \mathcal{V})$ a uniform space. On the function space $F:\{f: X\to Y\}=Y^X$, the topology of uniform convergence is finer than that of pointwise topology. The uniformity of uniform convergence on $F$ is generated by the base of elements $\{(f,g): (f(x),f(y))\in V, \forall x\in X\}$ for every $V\in\mathcal{V}$. Whereas the uniformity of pointwise convergence is generated by the subbase elements $\{(f,g):(f(x),g(x)\in V, \text{ for some }x\in X\}$. So u.c. uniformity has a smaller base than the p.c. uniformity. But why is u.c. uniformity finer than the latter?
I can understand why the topology of u.c. is finer than that of p.c., since a converging net still converges in a coarser topology. But I can't seem to understand it in terms of uniformity. Thanks in advance.

Sorry for asking silly questions. But I got the answer now.
Uniformity of u.c. is larger than that of p.c. because of the inclusion
$\quad\{(f,g):(f(x),g(x))\in V, \text{ for all }x\in X\}\\
\subset \{(f,g):(f(x),g(x))\in V, \text{ for infinitely many }x\in X\}\subset \{(f,g):(f(x),g(x))\in V, \text{ for }x\in F\in \mathcal{F}\},$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of all nonempty finite subsets of $X$.
The u.c. uniformity is generated by sets of first line as a base, and the p.c. uniformity by those of the third line as a base. So  a set of middle line lies in the uniformity of u.c. but not in that of p.c.. The two uniformities coincide iff $X$ is a finite set.
PS: However, in general, if, on a same set $S$, two uniformities $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ are such that $U\subset V$, for every base element $U\in \mathcal{U}$ and subbase element $V\in \mathcal{V}$, it's not necessarily true $\mathcal{U}\subset \mathcal{V}$. Because it's possible to have $V_1\cap V_2\notin \mathcal{U}$. This is why I was confused when posting this question.

The sets ${(f,g)\colon(f(x),g(x))\in V\text{ for some finitely many }x\in X}$ do not form a base for the uniformity of pointwise convergence, unless $X=\varnothing$ or $Y$ is a trivial uniform space: all these sets equal $Y^X\times Y^X$ since the empty set is finite! A true base can be obtained by modifying your base and defining a base element for each $V$ and each finite set $F$ of $X$.

@Noiril Satisfied now?
